# Are there technical benefits of UPDATE OR INSERT commands over DELETE ALL and INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb

So to be fair, I have seen some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427422/what-is-the-benefit-of-update-instead-of-doing-delete-and-then-insert-in-the-sam) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307212/update-or-delete-first-then-insert) but I believe these questions primarily ask about single row updates as well as assuming the actual data doesn't change.

In my case, I have a set of products a sale rep can offer. These overall products are maintained by a master table which defines them:

## master_table

```
ID  | Name  | status
---------------------
1   | prod1 |  1
2   | prod2 |  1
3   | prod3 |  0
4   | prod4 |  1
```

where status represents active (1) or inactive (0). An inactive product is not available for any representative to sell regardless of their settings in the rep table.

## rep_table

```
ID |  repID  |  status
------------------------
1  |   rep1  |   1
2  |   rep1  |   1
3  |   rep1  |   1
1  |   rep2  |   0
2  |   rep2  |   1
3  |   rep3  |   0
```

where status in this table is active (1) or inactive (0). Again, the status of the master table always overrides the rep_table status in terms of deciding which products a sales rep can offer.

The main issue I am running into is when we introduce new products for reps to sell. In a rep's administration portal, (s)he is able to activate or deactivate any set of products they wish to offer. When a user selects (form checkboxes) all of the products he/she wish to sell and hit submit a series of checks kick off:

1. Did the rep select a set of products?
2. Are the products selected in the correct format?
3. Does the list of selected products differ from that which they already had set when they logged in (if not, alert that no update will occur)?
4. Do all products selected in the form exist and are set to "active' in the master_table?

At that point, the logic then switches (currently) to the following for each product selected:

1. Update all products in the rep_table to inactive (for that particular rep)
2. If the product existed in the current set of products at login and the current status was set to inactive, then queue that product ID for active.
3. If the product passed did not exist in the current set of products at login, insert the new product in the rep_table and set to active.

The primary reason for updating ALL products for a particular rep to inactive at the start of the 'update' statement was due to the complicated nature of discovering which products that were set to 'active' at log-in were changed to 'inactive' on the product selection form.

I am wondering if instead of trying to figure out the status of the current product selections relative to that of those when the rep logged in, it isn't just easier to first delete ALL product IDs for a specific repID in rep_table then insert all at once. I know I am running 2 queries in this case but in scenarios where I have updates AND inserts in the same command, I am running a minimum of 2+ queries each time anyway.

Are there "technical" implications for deleting and inserting in this manner?

Notes: my table is InnoDB and I am running MySQL

Comment: Can you show us a create table statement with indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's usually what I do when it comes time to update options like that. It's generally easier to start a transaction, nuke the old options list, then insert the new options as selected by the user. It may be two queries, but they're easy queries.

The other option is to manually build a "changes" list - figure out what's new, figure out what's removed, and then delete the remove/insert the new ones. That's generally a lot more execution overhead, just to accomplish the same thing. And you'd STILL be running two queries anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you're indexed, the delete and insert may technically be your best option for performance.  Still, if you've got good indexes, an UPDATE or REPLACE statement that uses the index shouldn't be worth the concerns deleting all your data and then re inserting.

What if the Delete statement goes through, but before you can issue the insert, your server restarts apache and memory is dumped... seems far fetched, but can happen.   More users, more updates, more likely change...  You could put the DELETE and INSERT in a single transaction, but now your possibly locking a table--that's going to hit performance as well.

Comment: unless I am missing something this is what my PDO try catch blocks and commit() options are for. If the transaction truly locks that table per request it is something I have been unaware of for awhile.

Comment: @JM4 The try catch will handle if one command fails, but if you don't lock at table level, 2 people could run the same delete / insert pair and you could get a race condition.  I'm not sure if with INNODB transactions are entirly atomic to the entire insert / delete... only on the individual rows, but maybe someone will have better understanding on this

Comment: Transactions do not lock the table - because they are transactions. They must inhibit access a little bit because at some point the change has to be written to disk, but this is true for any query. You can also explicitly lock either certain datasets or the complete table - and this really is the only way a database can safely write to the table if there are no transactions available. Just look at MyISAM: No transactions, and any write request will lock the whole table and stop any read requests as well. InnoDB fully supports transactions, and would only lock affected rows.

Comment: @Sven with innodb assume you had transaction: first delete all rows with auto incrementing ids 1 through 1000000, second insert 1000000 new rows with auto incrementing ID's.  If 2 instances of the transaction these running at the same time, would one transaction have to finish in order before the other ran to get a predictable result or would they possibly overlap and or delete the others rows?

Comment: MySQL takes care not to create conflicting IDs because the primary index will be unique. But indeed there will be a lock that prevents both inserts to work concurrently, and one query might end up being deadlocked and thus fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the other answers, from a conceptual point of view, `UPDATE` modify existing rows. `DELETE`+`INSERT` will create new rows.

While rather theoretical at first, this has practical implications:

- For example, on the referential integrity of your database (*foreign keys* constraints, *cascades*).
- This could lead to different *triggers* to be fired too.
- Finally `DELETE`+`INSERT` might (and will probably) conflict with concurrent `UPDATES` on the same rows.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer. In my scenario there are (almost) never UPDATE only or Delete + Insert, it (would be rare). The common scenario would be UPDATE several (and these are multiple queries due to the nature of the data being sent) AND an INSERT call vs one DELETE + one INSERT.

Your point is taken but there will never (knock on wood) in which a delete+insert would ever occur simultaneously with an update.